How can I use a scoped service inside a transient or singleton service
Here I have a Background listener for Azure Service Bus for Topic, and the listener is registered as transient and the service client is registered as singleton - like this:
public static IServiceCollection AddASBMessageListeners(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (var listener in assembly.GetTypes().Where(a => !a.IsAbstract && a.IsDefined(typeof(QueueNameAttribute))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registering listener " + listener.Name);

        services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), listener);
    }

    return services;
}

public static IServiceCollection AddASBClient(this IServiceCollection services, IASBConfiguration configuration)
{
    var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions()
    {
        TransportType = configuration.TransportType
    };

    services.AddSingleton(s => new ServiceBusClient(configuration.ConnectionString,
        clientOptions));

    return services;
}

And the background listener implements IHostedService and IDisposable, and this listener class is registered with transient scope.
The listener class has this method:
public override async Task ProcessMessage(BrowserDataDeleteEvent message)
{
    try
    {
        using var scope = _logger.BeginScope("Consuming UserAccountDeleteEvenet for {Id}", message.UserId);

        var command = new DeleteUserPageVisitDataCommand(message.UserId.ToString());
        await _mediator.Send(command);

        _logger.LogInformation("UserAccountDeleteEvenet completed for UserId {UserId}", message.UserId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error processing userId {UserId}", message.UserId);
        throw;
    }
}

In this project I'm using CQRS pattern with mediator, and handler method has injected repository and repository is registered as scoped service, that's where the exception comes in, when listener try to execute the send method, it says

MediatR.Unit from root provider because it requires scoped service 

I already tried IServiceProvider option, and it works inside handler class, but not in the Listener class ProcessMessage method, is there any other way to use the same method inside within the ProcessMessage?
When I use option inside listener class like this:
public override async Task ProcessMessage(BrowserDataDeleteEvent message)
{
    try
    {
        using(var scoped = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {

            var scopedProcessingService = scoped.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

            using var scope = _logger.BeginScope("Consuming UserAccountDeleteEvenet for {Id}", message.UserId);

            var command = new DeleteUserPageVisitDataCommand(message.UserId.ToString());
            await scopedProcessingService.Send(command);

            _logger.LogInformation("UserAccountDeleteEvenet completed for UserId {UserId}", message.UserId);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error processing userId {UserId}", message.UserId);
        throw;
    }
}

I get the following error, when app builds:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Api.Listeners.UserAccountDeletedEventListener': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider' while attempting to activate 'Api.Listeners.UserAccountDeletedEventListener'.)'


Does this answer your question? How to use scoped dependency injection in singleton

When you say it does not work in the Listener class ProcessMessage method, why? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? It should work in there just fine.

@DavidG question updated with more details

You haven't included the full exception message, it should tell you what service it cannot inject into your hosted service.

@DavidG, inner exception part 1 says,
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Api.Listeners.UserAccountDeletedEventListener': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider' while attempting to activate 'Api.Listeners.UserAccountDeletedEventListener'

and 2
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider' while attempting to activate 'Api.Listeners.UserAccountDeletedEventListener'.

Were you trying to inject ServiceProvider instead of IServiceProvider, because this error message suggests so.

@DavidG i'm trying to do this inside the ProcessMessage method, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task

That does not answer my question

The problem is that services are usually scoped because they either require time-sensitive resources (like a transaction or a database connection), or need cleanup once they have completed their task.
Singleton services never end (until the application quits), and transient services have no defined lifetime. So, the very things that scoped services require are not possible.
To circumvent that, you need to define a lifetime for your invocations against the scoped services and ensure that you end the lifetime correctly (like committing transactions if everything went well).
That's done like this:
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourService>();
    service.DoSomething();

    scope.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>().SaveChanges();
}

You might want to move the lifetime management and service resolution to a specific class to hide the service location.
Microsoft also has an approach documented about hosted services here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

This is why I marked the question as a duplicate.
